# How to add auto-increment column in aspnetuser table while implementing asp.net identity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

How to add auto-increment column in AspNetUsers table while implementing asp.net identity? I do not prefer to change much the existing code and any simple workaround is also fine for me.

Comment: Please read [ask] and elaborate. By default, that table already gets an identity column, and tables can have at most one identity column. What exactly did you do, what did that result in and what do you want to change?

Comment: @CodeCaster If you know asp.net identity, it is clear enough. If not, you can't answer. So i think it is clear enough to get answer.

Comment: I know plenty about ASP.NET and ASP.NET Identity, you might consider checking my profile before making such claims. You on the other hand haven't read [ask]. You haven't included all relevant details (or rather, none whatsoever) in your question. What does your user entity look like? Does it have an `[[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]]` on its `Id` property?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for a column which value will auto increment (as per your question) then just add a column to the AspNetUsers table and make it auto incremental.

```
Personid int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

By default, the starting value for AUTO_INCREMENT is 1, and it will increment by 1 for each new record.

Comment: If I add an auto increment column, do i have to add this column in ApplicationUser class as well? Because I have to retrieve auto id of current user.

Comment: Yes, you have to add a property to the ApplicationUser class which will give you the value of the retrieved user.

Answer (score 0):

To add an autoincrement column named "PersonId" in AspNetUsers table:

```html
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string PersonId { get; set; }
}
```

Then add-migration and update-database.